# Testing if unsorted sets are disjoint in linear time. (homework problem)

Tags: algorithm

Problem:
Two sets A and B have n elements each. Assume that each element is an integer in the range [0, n^100]. These sets are not necessarily sorted. Show how to check whether these two sets are disjoint in O(n) time. Your algorithm should use O(n) space.

My original idea for this problem was to create a hash table of set A and search this hash table for each of the elements in B. However, I'm not aware of any way to create a hash table of a data set with this range that only takes O(n) space. Should I be considering a completely different approach?

UPDATE:
I contacted the professor regarding this problem asking about implementing a hash table and his response was:
Please note that hashing takes O(1) time for the operations only on an average. We need a worst case O(n) time algorithm for this problem.

So it seems the problem is looking for a different approach...

Comment: Is it definitely [0,n^100], not [0,2^100]? Thing is, the number n^100 has 100 * log n digits. You can't even *read* n of them in O(n) time, let alone do anything with them. It may be that the question has got itself confused between what `n` means in this question, and what it usually means in complexity analysis (the size of the input in bits).

Comment: I rechecked the assignment and the range is definitely [0,n^100]. I suppose the problem assumes that a number can be read independently of its magnitude/number of digits.

Comment: Hmm. If the question is assuming that, then perhaps it would allow you to store pointers to the numbers (O(1) space independently of its number of digits) and also compute hashcodes and compare values in O(1) time independently of the number of digits. Ridiculous assumption, but I think that otherwise the question is impossible.

Comment: Depending on the representation of the number, an effective hashing scheme can use the length of the number, and a few MSBs, LSBs, etc., which would be O(1).

Comment: @Steve, the standard assumpion is that you can perform operations on O(log n) bits in O(1) time. In this case, with the range [0, n^100], the constant hidden by big-O is roughly 100. Kind of weird, but it does fit with the standard assumption.

Comment: @jonderry: I guess so, I've never really seen a formal model of this. So if we can assume that we can operate on values up to n^100 in constant time, can we also assume that we store values up to n log n (the size of the input, hence indexes into the input) in constant space? If so, then the question is really no different than if it *had* been a 2^100 limit.

Comment: @Steve, yes you are correct. O(lg n) bits is generally considered O(1) memory unless with are specifically talking about bits. OP is the same problem as if the range were [0, n], with the same standard hashing solution, just with an extra constant factor of 100.

Comment: How can hashing be the right answer? The problem states that n can be in a range of 0 to n^100. If you use hashing, there could chances that all n numbers can fall into a single bucket and so for each element, you would need to look up n times and in worst case, the solution can become O(n^2)

Answer (score 6):

**Input:** Arrays A[m], B[n]

**Output:** True if they are disjoint, False otherwise

---

**1. Brute Force:** O(m*n) time, O(1) space

```
1. Search for each element of A into B
2. As soon as you get a match break and return false
3. If you reach till end, return true
```

**Advantage:** Doesn't modify the input

---

**2. Sort both** O(mlogm + nlogn + m + n)

```
1. Sort both arrays
2. Scan linearly
```

**Disadvantage:** Modifies the input

---

**3. Sort smaller** O((m + n)logm)

```
1. Say, m < n, sort A
2. Binary search for each element of B into A
```

**Disadvantage:** Modifies the input

---

**4. Sort larger** O((m + n)logn)

```
1. Say n > m, sort B
2. Binary search for each element of A into B
```

**Disadvantage:** Modifies the input

---

**5. Hashing** O(m + n) time, O(m) or O(n) space

**Advantage:** Doesn't modify the input

Comment: This answer ignores the range on the input values. Sorting can be better than Omega(n log n) when you bound the input values (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a hash table? Aren't they O(n) to create(Assuming they are all unique), then O(n) to search, being O(2n) = O(n)?

Comment: The concern is the space. Since the range ofpossible values is so large, wouldn't the hash table take larger space than O(n)?

Comment: A hash table uses a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to reduce the input domain to an appropriate size.

Comment: I don't have much experience in implementing hash functions. I'm not sure if for the purpose of the problem it would be acceptable to just say that an appropriate hash function is used such that the size of the hash table is O(n), or if I would actually need to outline how the hash function works.

Comment: "Hash tables are constant time and linear space" is a very common assumption, even though it's not strictly true.

Comment: @Strilanc: agree, especially since there are so many strategies to implement one. With a domain correctly defined though it should be possible to choose such an implementation I think.

Answer (score 1):

A hash set will work fine. It's extremely common to assume hash sets/tables are constant time per operation even though that's not strictly true.

Note that hash sets/tables absolutely only use space proportional to the elements inserted, not the potential total number of elements. You seem to have misunderstood that.

If "commonly assumed to be good enough" is unacceptable for some reason, you can use radix sort. It's linear in the total representation size of the input elements. (Caveat: that's slightly different from being linear in the number of elements.)

Comment: So for implementing a radix sort, if the runtime is O(nk), is there a manipulation to the input that should be done first to lower the key lengths (k), otherwise the average key length could be as high as 100log(n) (base 10), so we'd have O(nlogn), or maybe I'm misunderstanding the description I'm reading on radix sort.

Comment: For instance, could the two methods be combined in such a way that the n elements are hashed into a table of size n with hash function such that the hash value has a set length regardless of the input value, then perform radix sort on the hash table based on the hash values? This seems roundabout, but as noted in the update to the original problem statement, searching the hash set is not applicable as it does not have "worst case" O(1) runtime.

Comment: @ejf071189: Hash values always have a set length, in general they are stored in the native word of the underlying platform, so you can assume 64 bits on most computers. The problem is about collisions, since you are reducing the space used for representation several integers might share the same hash: this is a degenerate case that should be assumed for worst-case analysis, unless you can prove it cannot happen (perfect hash).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I didn't expect such answers from SO community but never mind. The question explicitly states that the algorithm should take O(n) space and time complexity, therefore we can rule out algorithms involving hashing since in the **worst case** hashing is not O(n).

Now I was going through some texts and found that the problem of finding whether 2 sets are reducible or not is *reducible* to the sorting problem. This is very standard when studying the lower bounds of many algorithms.
[Actual lines from the book DESIGN METHODS AND ANALYSIS OF ALGORITHMS
By S. K. BASU · 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSuTG.png).

Here the author clearly states that set disjointedness is clearly Omega(nlogn)

Comment: The bound on the values in the array (max n^100) invalidates your argument. The limited range allows sorting in O(n) time -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unordered_map<string,int>m;
    int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    string a,b; // for storing numbers upto n^100
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a;
        m[a]=1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>b;
        if(m[b])
        {
            cout<<"Not disjoint";
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    cout<<"Disjoint";
    return 0;
}
```

Time complexity : O(n)
Auxiliary space : O(n)

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can radix sort the inputs, in base n.

This will take 101 iterations through each array (because the input numbers are in the range 0 to n^100).

Once you've sorted the inputs, you can compare them in the obvious way in O(n) time.

Note: for the radix sort to run in O(n) time, you need to check that extracting the k'th digit (base n) of an input number is O(1). You can do that with (k-1) divisions by n and a modulo operation. Since k is at most 101, this is O(1).

---

<sup>side note</sup>
I note that kennytm@ gave a similar answer is 2010, but the answer was deleted after commenters noted that "Radix sort is O(nk) time, where n is the number of keys, and k is the average key length. Since the max key value is n^100, the max key length would be 100 log n. So, this would still be O(n log n), same as all of the best sorting algorithms."

Note that this comment is incorrect -- the maximum key length is 101, because the key is a sequence of numbers some base, and is not measured in bits.